# How long does advancing levels take?

Tags: character-advancement, time, rolemaster

Are there any rules about the amount of time level progression takes in Rolemaster Classic?

I am trying to work out a time cost for Characters advancing levels whilst events are occurring in other parts of the world.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean? Your question could be about how long characters need to practice to advance a skill, in addition to actually acquiring the XP. Or you could be asking about characters "out of play" advancing levels as time passes. Or something else entirely. The answer would have to reference rather different pieces of the rules for each of these cases. Also, are you referring to a specific version of Rolemaster?

Comment: Thanks for your consideration of the question but I have worked it out. It was about out of play length of time it takes to train up.

Comment: I cannot give you chapter and verse of the optional rule right now, but the way I play it, if a character did exercise the skill in question during play, or had reasonable opportunity to practice it out-of-play, I do not require extra practice time. (E.g. a fighter leveling up skill in weapons he had used in combat.) Practice time should be required only for skills the character had no opportunity to practice otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Rolemaster Classic, but as I understand it (and remember reading it), [the RMC rules are a reworking of RM2 rules](http://ironcrown.com/rolemaster/rolemaster-past/), and in those rules in Character Law, they reference no timescales for learning.

However, in that same book, there are optional rules (found separately from advancement rules; in my 1989 edition, on page 83 of Character Law, there is a section: **Additional Rules for Skill Acquisition (13.5.2)** that starts with the following text.

> **PRACTICE & STUDYING** - When using this rule, a certain amount of time must be spent practicing and/or studying a skill to be developed
>   (whichever is appropriate). The amount of time spent should be
>   determined by the Gamemaster depending on his world system and the
>   pace that he wants to set for his game.  The suggested values are 1
>   day/skill rank and 1 week for a spell list.  This practice or study
>   can occur anytime after the skills have been chosen for development.
>
> The practice should take approximately 8 hours per day.  The time
>   could be spread over a long period of time at 8 hours per skill rank
>   and 56 hours per spell list.  Under some world systems (and for some
>   races) this might be more or less than 8 hours per day.

It goes on with equipment, facilities, material, and meditation needed.

This seems to depend on you using the development system as intended, it appears, which many do not do, i.e. Creating a character consists of adolescence and apprenticeship, and you develop the 1st level before you start to play, then train that level at or before the time you get to level 2.